# Auto responsive layout for android mobile and tablet

Tags: android, mobile, screen, tablet, responsive

I am trying to develop an app, which support all mobile and tablet devices of every screen size and density, but every time i got some changes in UI for different screen sizes for example in image below i put three text on screen but it always change its location in different screen devices.

I tried smallest width screen(600,720,320,480) and screen size(S,N,L,X) but both are not working properly,
 is there anyone who can help me with specific data. please dont refer developer android site because i looked so many website but they only describe android screen specification, they dont give any proper solution. please give me any proper solution or project sample will be better.

thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1uKU.png

Comment: please create different dimen in values folder.

Comment: dimen-hdpi, dimen-hdpi,dimen-sw600dp,dimen-sw720dp

Comment: how i decide how much difference i have to give in dimen for (mdpi,hdpi,lhdpi,xhdpi), is there any fix parameter for different folders or i have to create manually for every screen. and how many screens i have to design for support all devices...?

Comment: declare values folder decide name my last comment

Comment: Example : ==>values-hdpi
<dimen name="txt_10">11sp</dimen>
==> values-mdpi
<dimen name="txt_10">10sp</dimen>
==> values-sw600dp
<dimen name="txt_10">15sp</dimen>
==>values-sw720dp
<dimen name="txt_10">30sp</dimen>

Comment: i got your point, i just want to ask is their any relation between 11sp,10sp,15sp,30sp or i have to check it manually in layouts for different screen

Comment: yes all screen size different dr.. example : hdpi normal size and sw600dp is  7inch tab.. screen size different values different. not other relation

Comment: ok thanks brother...on more think.. how many screen i have to design to support all devices.

Comment: no dear only one screen design but values assign this type.. android:textSize="@dimen/txt_16" . all device values direct get screen vice

Comment: okk thanks, it is really very helpful